# How to get popcorn.js working on dynamically loaded content?

Tags: mongodb, jquery, popcornjs

I've followed this tutorial:

http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-101

*Tutorial Code*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // ensure the web page (DOM) has loaded
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

     // Create a popcorn instance by calling Popcorn("#id-of-my-video")
     var pop = Popcorn("#ourvideo");

     // add a footnote at 2 seconds, and remove it at 6 seconds
     pop.footnote({
       start: 2,
       end: 6,
       text: "Pop!",
       target: "footnotediv"
     });

     // play the video right away
     pop.play();

      }, false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video height="180" width="300" id="ourvideo" controls>
      <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.mp4">
      <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.ogv">
      <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.webm">
    </video>
    <div id="footnotediv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And can run this locally.

In Firebug, I see the `footnote` div update from:

`<div style="display: none;">Pop!</div>`

to:

`<div style="display: inline;">Pop!</div>`

On a live site however, I am loading my page html from a MongoDB database via Ajax and the footnote display functionality doesn't seem to be working.

Thinking this might have something to do with needing to 're-initialise' after the content has loaded, I've added the popcorn.js functionality to a function called on click:

*Function*

```
<script>
function myPopcornFunction() {
var pop = Popcorn("#ourvideo");
pop.footnote({
start: 2,
end: 6,
text: "Pop!",
target: "footnotediv"
});
pop.play();
}
</script>
```

*Call*

```
$(document).on("click","a.video", function (e) {
// passing values to python script and returning results from database via getJSON()
myPopcornFunction();
});
```

This doesn't seem to have an effect.

No `footnotediv` content is loaded when the video plays.

The video is also not playing automatically.

It's hard to reproduce in jsFiddle with dynamic content, so is there a generic approach to ensuring popcorn works with dynamically loaded content?

*Firebug Error on click*

```
TypeError: k.media.addEventListener is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a timing issue in that originally I had made a call to the `myPopcornFunction()` *outside* of the function which loaded the content (a `getJSON()` function).  When I placed the call within the same block as the `getJSON()` function, things seemed to maintain their 'order' and popcorn could work correctly.

**Before**

```
$(document).on("click","a.video", function (e) {
$.getJSON("/path", {cid: my_variable, format: 'json'}, function(results){
$("#content_area").html("");
$("#content_area").append(results.content);
});
e.preventDefault();
myPopcornFunction();   // the call WAS here
});
```

**After**

```
$(document).on("click","a.video", function (e) {
$.getJSON("/path", {cid: my_variable, format: 'json'}, function(results){
$("#content_area").html("");
$("#content_area").append(results.content);
myPopcornFunction();   // the call is now HERE
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `myPopcornFunction()` was the same as in the original post.